# ¿Por que no me toma los estilos en CSS, pero si los estilos en linea?

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo cascada, especificidad, etc... Y me esta surgiendo un problema.
Resulta que estaba practicando lo mas bien, pero de la nada dejo de tomarme los estilos en CSS,pero a la hora de utilizar estilos en linea me los toma con normalidad.
SIGUE >>>>>>

CODIGO HTML:

```
 <html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Empezamos con el CSS</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>PROBADO EL MODELO DE CASCADA</h1>
<h2 class="tit2" atributo="colore">PROBANDO CLASES, PSEUDO-CLASES Y ATRIBUTOS</h2>
<h3 id="tit3" class="tit-3">LOS ID TIENEN MAS JERARQUIA QUE LAS CLASES, PSEUDOCLASES Y ATRIBUTOS</h3>
<h4 id="tit4" class="tit-4" style="color:palevioletred;">PERO EL ESTILO EN LINEA (STYLE) TIENE MAS JERARQUIA QUE TODOS</h4>

<div>
<p> probando estilos css, no entiendo por que no me esta tomando estilos wtf</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

mi problema surge en la etiqueta `p`, cuando le doy estilo en CSS no lo toma, en cambio si le agrego estilo en linea, si.
Los estilos en las demás etiquetas las puedo modificar sin problema.

```
 p{
color: green;
background-color: red;
}
```

---

Este seria el codigo CSS:

```
h1{
    color: red;
    }
    h1{
    color: green;
    }
    h2{
    color: green;
    }
    .tit2{
    color: blue;
    }
    .tit2:hover{
    color: red;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 2px;
    }
    [atributo="colore"]{
    color: grey;
    }
    h3{
    color: green;
    }
    #tit3{
    color: darkviolet;
    }
    .tit-3{
    color: lightskyblue;
    }
     h4{
    color: red; 
    }
    #tit4{
    color: steelblue;
    }
    .tit-4{
    color: beige;
    }
```

Comment: Lo más probable es que la ruta que le estás asignando al fichero index.css no es la correcta.

Comment: a que te refieres con estilos en linea?

Comment: sube una imagen de la estructura de tus carpetas tambien

Comment: Es que me deja modificar los estilos en los otros elementos <h>, todos los elementos que le siguen después no. Esta bien linkeado, y las carpetas están en orden. Cabe destacar que esto comenzó a ocurrir después de haber usado !important (ya lo borre y no me toma estilos)

Comment: Hola @binthc, según tu declaración **Es que me deja modificar los estilos en los otros elementos <h>**, está claro que el problema está en tu archivo **.css**, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos verlo.

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de chequear mi pregunta!!

Comment: @binthc, buenisimo, sería bueno que agregaras en tu pregunta el código erróneo y que en la respuesta expliques como lo resolviste, después marcas la respuesta como aceptada, para que así pueda servir a otros.

Answer (score 0):

Tus estilos funcionan correctamente como puedes ver en esta prueba ejecutando todo el código. Asegúrate si estás cargando una hoja de estilos de que los archivos están bien nombrados y las rutas bien en relativo o en absoluto son correctas dentro de tu estructura de carpetas, así como que se están llamando desde el lugar apropiado dentro de tu html.

```css
h1{
    color: red;
    }
h1{
    color: green;
    }
h2{
    color: green;
    }
.tit2{
    color: blue;
    }
.tit2:hover{
    color: red;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 2px;
    }
[atributo="colore"]{
    color: grey;
    }
h3{
    color: green;
    }
#tit3{
    color: darkviolet;
    }
.tit-3{
    color: lightskyblue;
    }
h4{
    color: red; 
    }
#tit4{
    color: steelblue;
    }
.tit-4{
    color: beige;
    }
p{
    color: green;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Empezamos con el CSS</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>PROBADO EL MODELO DE CASCADA</h1>
<h2 class="tit2" atributo="colore">PROBANDO CLASES, PSEUDO-CLASES Y ATRIBUTOS</h2>
<h3 id="tit3" class="tit-3">LOS ID TIENEN MAS JERARQUIA QUE LAS CLASES, PSEUDOCLASES Y ATRIBUTOS</h3>
<h4 id="tit4" class="tit-4" style="color:palevioletred;">PERO EL ESTILO EN LINEA (STYLE) TIENE MAS JERARQUIA QUE TODOS</h4>

<div>
<p> probando estilos css, no entiendo por que no me esta tomando estilos wtf</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comparto a continuación un enlace a documentación sobre el [uso y carga de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics) que creo que podrá resultar de utilidad.